# Canvas - Create an image item above tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I prepared a simple example using the Entry and Button I placed on my Canvas. I want the image (panel)(create_image) that occurs when I press the Button to appear above the Button and the Entry (to cover it) but when the image is created, it is created(panel) under the Button and the Entry. How can i solve this? Thanks...

```
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

w=Tk()

canvas =Canvas(width = 800, height = 800)
canvas.place(relx=0,rely=0)

background= Image.open("light.jpg").resize((700,700))
background=ImageTk.PhotoImage(background)

alert_panel= Image.open("alert_panel.png").resize((500,300))
panel=ImageTk.PhotoImage(panel)

canvas.create_image(0,0,image=background,anchor=NW)

def login():
    alert=canvas.create_image(100,200,image=alert_panel,anchor=NW)

entry=Entry(fg="black",bg="light gray")
entry.configure(highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
entry.insert(0,"Username:")
entry.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.17)

buton1=Button(text="L O G I N",highlightbackground="black",command=login)
buton1.place(relx=0.33,rely=0.27)

w.mainloop()
```

images used:
[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qeQ0.jpg)

[alert_panel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGdpN.png)

Comment: Right now you are creating and placing the widgets over the `Canvas`. Try using a `tkinter.Label` for the `alert_panel`

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually possible but you could create a function then when the button is click , you to switch between the position of the button and the image you want to create.as shown below :

```
def login():
    button1.place_forget()
    entry.place_forget()
    canvas.create_image(100,200,image=alert_panel,anchor=NW)
```

**Note :**
I choose `.place_forget()` to make the button and the entry disappear from the main window .(It's only a trick but I think it would answer your question)

Comment: `button1.place_forget()` would be much better.

Comment: @Ayyoub ESSADEQ        Thanks for your answer, your answer is logical, simple and useful but these codes of mine are just a simple example. Using this process in a complicated program wouldn't cause any problems, would it? Does it slow it down?

Comment: I don't think so , because `.place_forget()` is a built-in function which should be as optimized as possible .

Comment: (if you find my answer helpful please assign it as useful .Thanks a lot :) )

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't put the alert image above other widgets if the image is created inside the canvas using `.create_image(...)`.

Suggest to create a border-less transparent `Toplevel` to show the alert image:

```py
def login():
    #alert=canvas.create_image(100,200,image=alert_panel,anchor=NW)
    top = Toplevel(w)
    top.withdraw()
    top.overrideredirect(1) # make border-less window
    # make it like a transparent window
    trans_color = '#deaded'  # select a color not used by the alert image
    top.attributes('-transparentcolor', trans_color)
    # show the alert image
    alert = Label(top, image=panel, bg=trans_color)
    alert.pack()
    # put the popup at the center of root window
    top.update()
    x, y = w.winfo_rootx(), w.winfo_rooty()
    rw, rh = w.winfo_width(), w.winfo_height()
    tw, th = top.winfo_width(), top.winfo_height()
    top.geometry(f"+{x+(rw-tw)//2}+{y+(rh-th)//2}")

    top.bind('<Button-1>', lambda _: top.destroy()) # just a way to close the popup
    top.deiconify()
    top.grab_set()
```

Note that there is typo error on this line:

```py
panel=ImageTk.PhotoImage(panel)
```

It may be as below:

```py
panel = ImageTk.PhotoImage(alert_panel)
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply.
I added your codes to my own code but got _tkinter.TclError:'bad attribute "-transparentcolor": must be -alpha, -topmost, -zoomed, -fullscreen, or -type'
                                                                               I fixed it with top.attributes('-alpha', trans_color) but this time I got an error like this:_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "#deaded"
  
What should I do, sorry I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @dest `-transparentcolor` is only supported in Windows.  So my suggestion is not working for you then.

Comment: I understand the situation. Thanks for your reply and interest.